# CONCAT in Update query using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to update a column 'trackId' by concating columns 'id' & 'created_at'. I have tried below query but not working.

```
$data = array();

$data['ip'] = $ip;
$data['updated_at'] = time();
$data['trackId'] = "CONCAT(id, created_at)";

$this->db->where('id', 123)->update(MY_TABLE, $data);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to update the column you use `set()` and not in where clause

Comment: @Nawin can you post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer. after suggestion of @Nawin.

```
$data = array();

$data['ip'] = $ip;
$data['updated_at'] = time();
$this->db->set('trackId', "CONCAT(id, created_at)", FALSE);

$this->db->where('id', 123)->update(MY_TABLE, $data);
```

It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for update concat:

```
$data['ip'] = $ip;
$data['updated_at'] = time();

$this->db->where('id', 123);
$this->db->set("trackId", "CONCAT(id, created_at)", false);
$this->db->update(MY_TABLE, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You check CONCAT rules and you should mention created_at values,

Below check this code

```
$data['trackId'] = "CONCAT(trackId, created_at)";
```